# Ghashtable storing double

Tags: c, double, glib

Hello I was wondering if it was possible to store a double into a ghashtable considering there is no gdouble_to_pointer methdod. I am following a tutorial I found online by IBM http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/section5.html  , but I can't seem to find a way to use an int as a key and a double as the value being stored. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an int as a key, you should use g_int_hash() and g_int_equal() when you create the GHashTable.

As far as using doubles for values goes... you can't. The problem is that you cannot guarantee that sizeof (void *) >= sizeof (double), so you can't use a trick like GINT_TO_POINTER()

Comment: okay thanks thats what I wanted to know :/ what in your opinion would be the best way to do a dictionary type structure using ints as keys? I could make my own but just trying to see if there are available options! thanks

Comment: Sadly, you'll probably have to write your own if you are sticking with C. Unless you are ok with malloc'ing your double values to store in the hash table?

Comment: sorry I'm a bit new to C  how would you do this?  I know malloc can dynamically assign memory but how would that help? or are you suggesting making a pointer and giving the hashmap a pointer to assigned memory instead of a hard value? Thanks!

Comment: or what if you made a string hashtable and you entered all of the doubles as strings? would that work?

Comment: `GHashTable *table = g_hash_table_new_full (g_int_hash, g_int_equal, NULL, g_free); double *value = g_malloc (sizeof (double)); memcpy (value, &dbl, sizeof (double)); g_hash_table_insert (table, GINT_TO_POINTER (key), value);`

Comment: a hash table using doubles encoded into strings would "work"... but then you'd have to parse the values back out again which could get expensive.

Comment: i get a seg fault error when inserting into the hashtable, so I dont think itll work? using your code above

Comment: The problem seems to be g_int_hash, switch to using g_direct_hash and g_direct_equal instead.

Comment: okay so it does allow me to store the elements in the hashmap, but when I go to verify all the elements are 0.000, g_hash_table_foreach(table,(GHFunc) wide_open ,"key %d    value %f\n");

where wide open is void wide_open(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer user_data) {
 printf(user_data,(int)key,value);

Comment: nvm I'm stupid I figured it out. For those wondering you should store your value into a double before printing. Thanks so much mr jstedfast! You are a gentleman and a scholar